# Add new row to gridview that comes from a stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have the bellow `Gridview` that pulls data from a `stored procedure` that turns the data from vertical to horizontal with a pivot. I want to add a new row at a specific `RowNumber  5`. This row will be filled only with black color.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1"  runat="server" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" ShowHeader="true" CssClass="style3"  ForeColor="White"
                    OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
                    <EditRowStyle BorderColor="Black" ForeColor="Black" />
<Columns>
     <asp:ButtonField CommandName="ColumnClick" Visible="false" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a similar question to these.
Have a look on them

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/3cc334fb-9da0-48eb-b83e-0bec72c60d16
http://forums.asp.net/t/1670659.aspx/1

```
DataTable dt = GridView1.tables[0];
DataRow dr = new DataRow();
DataTable.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 5);
DataTable.AcceptChanges();

gv_list.DataSource = dt;
gv_list.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
DataRow dr = DataTable.NewRow();
DataTable.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 5);
DataTable.AcceptChanges();

gv_list.DataSource = DataTable;
gv_list.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you tell me how can i remove the format of the new row and write on this row ex."break"?